# Necessary trailheads for salesforce newcomer developer

Tags: trailhead, developer

what trailheads would you recommend to get overall knowledge for salesforce newcomer developer? Do you have some personal trailmixes to get hands on everything important? With prior development experience and somew

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to the community, if you provide your development background we can be more specific about which SF topic to suggest, even if you have none.

Comment: Hello and thank you, currently I work/learn with salesforce backend, rewriting old code so now I'm "locked" to that but with opportunities to choose what I wanna do.. I studied IT university and worked with SAP, JS, Java so I can write the code, see some limitations it has, but don't know about areas which are specific to Apex/Salesforce. From SAP I was few years working with CRM and other systems so I have some view about that, but naming of things is different. So I'd like to see some broad overview with some interconnected specific things, preferably, like mind map with links to details :D

Comment: Well, with your SF experience I reccomend to follow some or the trailmixes that Trailhead proposes. In those sections you can find a summary of most topics belonging (more or less) to the same tematic. If your purpose is to improve dev skills the most obvious to choose is the [Developer Trailmix](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/users/rtarkowski/trailmixes/developer-trailmix) which incapsulates  both developing and administration topics.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with one of the trailmix you prefer as an Admin or Developer respectively:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/force_com_admin_beginner
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/force_com_dev_beginner